# python regular expression for URL just "www.example.com"

Tags: python-3.x

I need python regex for "**www.example.com**"  (without quotes). 
example can be of any string.
I need it without any other text before "**www**" and after "**.com**"

Comment: You better don't parse urls with a custom regex, use a library. URLs are quite complicated: these can contain usernames, passwords, paths, query parameters,...

Comment: I don't know what that means I'm just a beginner in python. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Have a look at urlparse: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dedicated function from the standard library [urllib.parse.urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> parts = urlparse('http://www.example.org')
>>> parts
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.org', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> parts.netloc
'www.example.org'
```

Or you can use this regexp for a text:

```
>>> import re
>>> regexp = re.compile(r'\s*(www\.[^:\/\n]+\.com)\s*')
>>> urls = regexp.findall('Hello https://www.mywebsite.com/index.py?q=search bonjour...')
>>> urls
['www.mywebsite.com']
```